# Rasa integration with instagram

Tags: facebook, instagram, facebook-messenger, rasa

I am trying to integrate `rasa` with `instagram`. I am able to connect `rasa` with `facebook`. On the same line facebook also give instagram setting.

I tried to search some document for `rasa` with `instagram`. Is anyone able to connect, Please Help.

**Steps I followed. (Tried to follow same step performed for facebook messenger)**

- Created app on facebook developer and added `messenger setup` in the same.
- I have created instagram business account and connected to facebook
- Created facebook page linked with same instagram accound.
- In the app under `messenger` in `instagram settings`  (created on facebook developer) added facebook page created above and `PAGE ACCESS TOKEN` generated.
- `APP SECRETE` `PAGE ACCESS TOKEN` and `VERIFY TOKEN` added in rasa's `credential.yml` under facebook. Rasa server started with above `credential.yml`file

  `rasa run --credentials credentials.yml`
- Added webhook URL in facebook APP configuration
- All subscription added (for POC purpose added all)
  [image]

Is any other steps I should follow. Not sure it is possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

Instagram is not a channel currently supported by Rasa.

I would recommend creating a [custom channel connector](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/connectors/custom-connectors) by starting with the [Facebook Messenger channel connector](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/main/rasa/core/channels/facebook.py) as either the base class or as a template of how to get started.

Adding a link to the [Instagram Messaging API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/instagram) docs too for more resources in case you are not already familiar with this.

Answer (score 1):

As I searched through [RASA FROUME](https://forum.rasa.com/) and especially in [tutorial part](https://forum.rasa.com/c/getting-started-with-rasa/tutorials/11) there is a way to do this.

Read this link ***https://forum.rasa.com/t/rasa-chatbot-on-instagram/51762***
in here is completely described how to connect your rasa chatbot to Instagram and chat with

hope it helps